# Integrable variable $X$ , integral of the expected value of $|X|$ over a small set $A$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, P)$ be our probability space.

Prove that a random variable $X$ is integrable, that is $\mathbb{E}(X) < \infty$ $\iff$ $$\forall \varepsilon >0 \exists \delta>0 : \forall A \in \Sigma : P(A) < \delta \Rightarrow \int_A |X| \text{d}P< \varepsilon $$

When it comes to $\Rightarrow$, I can show that $$\sup \{ \mathbb{E}(|X| 1_A) \ : \ A \in \Sigma, P(A) \le \ \delta\}$$ tends to $0$ as $\delta \to 0$, using the Borel Cantelli lemma.

But I don't know what to do about the other direction.

Could you help me a bit?

Comment: In the statement you say $\forall \epsilon$ but then you don't use $\epsilon$ any more, it does not make sense.

Comment: @iiivooo Thanks for pointing that out. I've corrected that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $K>0$
$$
E|X| = \int_{|X|\le K}|X|\,dP + \int_{|X|> K}|X|\,dP$$
The first integral is bounded by $K$. Now you want the second integral to be finite. Any finite upper bound on the second integral will do. How do you do that?

Hint 1:

> The second integral can be made small if you can make $P(|X|>K)$ small (why?)

Hint 2:

> and $P(|X|>K)$ can be made small by choosing $K$.

Comment: We know that for any small $\varepsilon $ there exists a $\delta$ such that if $P(|X| \ge K) < \delta$, the integral is smaller than $\varepsilon$. This explains the first hint.

Comment: But I do not yet see gow to choose $K$.

Comment: Can you show that $P(|X|>K)\to0$ as $K\to\infty$?

Comment: No, I don't know how to show that. Could I ask for one more hint?

Comment: There are several ways to argue this. The most basic is: $1=P(|X|<\infty) = P(\bigcup_k\{k<|X|\le k+1\}) = \sum_kP(k<|X|\le k+1)$ by countable additivity of $P$.

Comment: So this equality shows that $P(k < |X| < k+1) \to 1$ as $k \to \infty$. And $1- P(k < |X| < k+1) = P(|X| \in (0, k) \cup (k+1, \infty)) \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$

Comment: Not exactly. If $y_k := P(k<|X|\le k+1)$ then $\sum_ky_k=1$ . Thus $\sum y_k$ is an infinite series that converges to a finite limit, so its tail tends to zero, i.e.  $\sum_{i\ge k}y_i\to0$ as $k\to\infty$.

Comment: Could you explain to me why $ \lim_{k \infty} \sum_{i \ge k} P(i < |X| \le i+1)$ gives us $P(|X|>K)$?

Comment: $|X|>k$ if and only if $k<|X|\le k+1$, or $k+1<|X|\le k+2$, or $k+2<|X|\le k+3$, or $\ldots$. So $P(|X|>k)=\sum_{i\ge k}P(i<|X|\le i+1)$. The limit is not involved here.

Comment: Ok, every time $|X|$ is bigger than $k$, but smaller than $k+1, k+2$ and so on. How stupid of me! Thank you a lot!